# How to pass a mysql local variable to python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I would like to pass a local variable from MySQL to python using MySQLdb module.

I know there are a lot of answers about the other way around (from python to mysql), and I am not looking for that.

I know also how to get any data from a table using

```
SELECT data_name 
FROM table_name
```

The affected rows can be fetched to get the result.

However, running a `SELECT @my_variable` from python returns an empty result.

```sql
LOCK TABLES `usedID` WRITE;

 /...*Do some stuff here*/

SELECT `lastaugID` FROM `usedID` INTO @ID;
UNLOCK TABLES;
SELECT @ID;
```

Executing the above snippet from mysql returns the expected result:

```sql
+-------+
| @ID   |
+-------+
| 58404 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But the passed value to python is an empty list.

Here is the python snippet making SQL query:

```py
def write_sql(self, sqlreq, sqlreqdict):
  if self.sockname:
      con = MySQLdb.Connect( unix_socket=self.sockname, user=self.sqluser,
                             passwd=self.sqlpasswd, db=self.sqldb,
                             cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor );
  else:
      con = MySQLdb.Connect( host=self.sqlhost, user=self.sqluser,
                             passwd=self.sqlpasswd, db=self.sqldb,
                             cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor );
  cursor = con.cursor();
  try:
      cursor.execute( sqlreq, sqlreqdict );
  except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, val:
      html.print_errmsg_exit( "Database integrity error: " + str(val) );
  res = cursor.fetchall();

  del cursor;
  con.commit();
  con.close();
  # Re-open the read-only cursors of the DB, to be able to process
  # a request to read the just-created  file:
  self.init_db();

return res
```

PS: Why not just read from the table directly? I need to lock the table and read the value before it is unlocked. If I read after unlocking, I might get a value that has been changed by another session.

Comment: Share the relevant python code which you are using right now.

Comment: Why do you want to use a local variable in Mysql, better to fetch the @ID variable in python using `ID = cursor.execute( SELECT lastaugID FROM usedID).fetchall()`

Comment: @Nishant Patel as mentioned at the end of the post: Why not just read from the table directly? I need to lock the table and read the value before it is unlocked. If I read after unlocking, I might get a value that has been changed by another session.
That is why I am using a local variable. If you have an idea about a better way to overcome this, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: In that case you can execute the sequence of LOCK, READ and UNLOCK, using your above queries.
`cursor.execute(LOCK TABLES usedID WRITE);ID = cursor.execute( SELECT lastaugID FROM usedID).fetchall();cursor.execute(UNLOCK TABLES)`